# Trying to style input type range but thumb doesnt get styled

Tags: css

im trying to style an `input type='range'` i am able to style the runnable track but for some reason the thumb isnt getting styled fully

this is my code:

```
<input type="range" min="0" max="100 " value="50" id="slider" class="volume">
```

```
#slider {
    width: 0;
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translateX(-50px);
    position: absolute;
    transition: 0.5s;
}

#slider::-webkit-slider-runnable-track {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    height: 3px;
    background-color: var(--white2);
}

#slider::-webkit-slider-thumb {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    height: 7px;
    width: 7px;
    transform: translateY(-5px);
    background-color: var(--white);
    border: 1px solid;
}
```

somehow the `transform: translateY(-5px);` is getting applied but nothing else is.

Comment: Kindly put the html part too so we can see the style working. Thanx

Comment: @Leothelion there you go

Comment: Please look at the code you have provided and make it more complete. For example, how are the --white CSS properties defined, and what stops the slider having width 0 and opacity 0? It helps us if you can provide a working snippet which you have tested as showing your problem. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, it was an issue cause by an experimental chrome flag :/ sorry for wasting your time.